# How to calculate center of mass acceleration?

Tags: drake

[`CalcBiasCenterOfMassTranslationalAcceleration`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a029b22a36d5c6ee85247b9c1cfe84c6b) seems to provide part of the center of mass acceleration, as stated in the description

> abias_ACcm is the part of a_ACcm (Ccm's translational acceleration) that does not multiply ṡ, equal to abias_ACcm = J̇_v_ACcm * s. This allows a_ACcm to be written as a_ACcm = J̇_v_ACcm * s + abias_ACcm.

So how do I find the other part of a_ACcm, i.e. J̇_v_ACcm * s?

I looked at [`CalcJacobianCenterOfMassTranslationalVelocity`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#aa4e686199a5e9ddee98538741b7a0382) but that only gives me J_v_ACcm_E (which seems to be providing the same information as `CalcBiasCenterOfMassTranslationalAcceleration`, with the only difference being the latter is multiplied by ṡ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how do I find the other part of a_ACcm, i.e. J̇_v_ACcm * s? (I believe it should be J̇_v_ACcm * ṡ btw)

I think drake's documentation is wrong. I think the other part of a_ACcm should be J_v_ACcm * ṡ, namely the Jacobian multiplies the joint acceleration, not Jacobian_dot multiplies the joint acceleration (J̇_v_ACcm is time derivative of the Jacobian, notice the small dot on top of the capital letter `J`).

As you said, you could call `CalcJacobianCenterOfMassTranslationalVelocity` to compute the Jacobian J_v_ACcm, you then multiply this with the joint acceleration, and that is the term J_v_ACcm * ṡ

Comment: Documentation fixed in Drake PR [#13645](https://github.com/robotlocomotion/drake/pull/13645).